# Why does Spring Webflux streaming halts for sometime in between and then resumes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

Here is the return code where am using aggregation to get data from MongoDB using Spring Webflux. When I try for records more than 15000, it looks like after around 6000 records doOnNext halts and next one is coming after a minute. So is there any way to check what is going in background or is this a common issue that streaming halts and resumes after a minute?

````
            aggregation.withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(true).build()),
            "my_collection", Document.class).
            doOnNext(value -> {
            log.info("-----------doOnNext-------------");
            }).
            doOnCancel(()->{
            log.info("-----------doOnCancel-------------");
            }). 
            doOnError(ex->{
            log.info("-----------doOnError-------------");
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
            }).
            onBackpressureBuffer(1000, BufferOverflowStrategy.DROP_OLDEST).
            doOnComplete(()->{
            log.info("-----------doOnComplete-------------");
            })
            ;```
````